# 'arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc' vs. 'arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc' compilation difference

Tags: c, assembly, arm, cross-compiling, inline

I'm writing a C program with inline assembly function that compares two strings if they are same.

When I compile it with 'arm-none-linux-gneabi-gcc' and 'arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc', the results are different. The difference seems to come from keyword 'none' which is place for [vendor] according to google search.

My questions are

1. Is this the cause of the difference in the results?
2. If so, what is set as [vendor] in 'arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc'?

**My code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * intoneplus(int * i);
char * charoneplus(char * c);

int my_strcmp(const char *src1, const char *src2);

int main(void)

{
    const char *a = "Hello world!";
    const char *a1 = "Hello world!";
    const char *a2 = "hello aorld!";

    if(my_strcmp(a, a1)==0)
        printf("a and a1 are same sentence\n");
    else
        printf("a and a1 are different\n");

    if(my_strcmp(a, a2)==0)
        printf("a and a2 are same sentence\n");
    else
        printf("a and a2 are different\n");

    return 0;

}

int my_strcmp(const char *src1, const char *src2)
{
    int ch1, ch2, ret=0;
    __asm__ (
        "loop:\n\t"         
        "LDRB %[ch1], [%[src1]], #1 \n\t LDRB %[ch2], [%[src2]], #1\n\t" 
        "CMP %[ch1], %[ch2]\n\t"                         
        "MOVNE %[ret], #1\n\t BNE done \n\t"                     
        "CMP %[ch1], #0\n\t BNE loop\n\t"               
        "done:\n\t"                         

        :[ret]"=r"(ret)                         
        :[src1]"r"(src1),[src2]"r"(src2),[ch1]"r"(ch1),[ch2]"r"(ch2)    

    );
    return ret;
}
```

**Compilation and execution results :**

```
@ubuntu:~/test$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o practice2.out practice2.c -static
@ubuntu:~/test$ qemu-arm practice2.out
464281
a and a1 are different
1
a and a2 are different
@ubuntu:~/test$ arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o practice2.out practice2.c -static
@ubuntu:~/test$ qemu-arm practice2.out
0
a and a1 are same sentence
1
a and a2 are different
```

Comment: Your inline asm is unsafe to compile with optimization enabled.  You tell the compiler that some vars are pure inputs (`"r"`), but then you modify them inside the asm template.  Also, you dereference pointer inputs without telling the compiler that the pointed-to memory is also an input.  [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56432259). You're also missing a `"cc"` clobber (condition codes). All the brokenness is hidden by the calling convention when you compile with optimization disabled so `my_strcmp` can't inline

Comment: Hence the general advice: avoid inline assembly unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Then could you tell me how it should be written?  The [ch1]"+r"(ch1)' [ch2]"+r"(ch2)' should be written in output? For src1, src2  I should add input for *src1 and *src2? Lastly, you're saying that the command without 'none' is unoptimized?